# How to disable a LinkControl inside a Process Template TFS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a LinkControl inside a Process Template which is enabled by defualt after Save Button Clicked , i need a programmatic way with c#  to disable it or disable its toolbar buttons.

Related Links i search with

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997890.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disable any of the buttons with c#.

You may be able to do something with JavaScript.

Comment: Not my fort, but you could look at Tiago's Taskboard Enhancer for inspiration: http://pascoal.net/task-board-enhancer/